# dynamic background image jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to dynamically change all `<h2>` background position with jQuery and after that change the `<h2>` size to 100%.
My code is the following:

css:

```
h2 { display: inline-block;}
```

jquery:

```
$("h2").css("background-position", "0px 0px").animate({
    'background-position-x': $(this).width(),
    'background-position-y': "3px",
    'width': "100%"
});
```

But the `$(this)` not working because this not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("h2").css("background-position","0px 0px").each( function() {
  var h2 = $(this);
  h2.animate({
    'background-position-x': h2.width(),
    'background-position-y': "3px",
    'width': "100%"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an explicit loop:

```
$("h2").each(function () {
    $(this).css("background-position", "0px 0px");
    $(this).animate({
        'background-position-x': $(this).width() + "px",
        'background-position-y': "3px",
        'width': "100%"
    });
});
```